# Long over int division

Tags: java, division

Question was asked before. I didn't agree with the answer. Why does division work this way? Please see the line long aslong=n/(a*b)

FYI. a similar question few years ago.
[Unexpected result in long/int division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12314889/unexpected-result-in-long-int-division)

```
long n=8589934592l; // =2^33 
int nasint=(int)n;  // it can't fit into int so it's zero.          
int a=2097152; int b=1024;
int asint=(int) n/(a*b); // n is cast into zero. so answer is zero.
long aslong=n/(a*b); // don't the int get cast into long?
long aslong2=n/((long)a*(long)b); // as expected

System.out.println("long n=" + n + " as int=" + nasint); // long n=8589934592 as int=0
System.out.println("asint=" + asint); // asint=0
System.out.println("aslong=" + aslong); // aslong=-4
System.out.println("aslong2=" + aslong2); // aslong2=4
```

Comment: But they're multiplied (and overflowed) before the cast.

Comment: Incidentally, it's a really good idea to use a capital `L` in a `long` literal.  That number on the first line of your code looks far too much like it ends with a `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java Language Specification says the following.

[15.7.3.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7.3) "Evaluation Respects Parentheses and Precedence":

> The Java programming language **respects the order of evaluation indicated explicitly by parentheses** and implicitly by operator precedence.

[15.7.2.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7.2) "Evaluate Operands before Operation":

> The Java programming language guarantees that **every operand of an operator** (except the conditional operators `&&`, `||`, and `? :`) **appears to be fully evaluated before any part of the operation itself is performed**.

This means that `(a*b)` is evaluated *before* the division operator in `n/(a*b)`, and since both `a` and `b` are `int` variables, the multiplication is done as `int`. The result is then undergoes a "[Widening Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)" to `long` for the division.

---

Since I'm quoting the JLS, let me quote this one too *(special thanks to David Wallace for noticing)*:

[3.10.1.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1) "Integer Literals":

> An integer literal is of type `long` if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter `L` or `l` (ell); otherwise it is of type `int` ([§4.2.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1)).
>
> ***The suffix `L` is preferred**, because the letter `l` (ell) is often hard to distinguish from the digit `1` (one).*

Comment: Only because I stared at it wondering whether OP really thought that 2^33 was an odd number, until the penny dropped.

Comment: I don't know how to give David a credit but I'm saying thank you)